# Is there a method to convert each element of source array from one type to another type?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, generics

This **Transfrom** function transforms each element of source array from one type to another type by some rule. It has 2 parameters, one of them is an Interface

```
public static TResult[] Transform<TSource, TResult>(this TSource[] source, ITransformer<TSource, TResult> transformer)
        {
            if (source == null || transformer == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            }

            if (source.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Array is empty");
            }

            var res = Array.ConvertAll(source, transformer.Transform(source));

            return res;
        }
```

There is an error because parameter of *transformer.Transform(source)* cannot convert from TSource[] to TSource

Here is the interface ITransformer

```
public interface ITransformer<in TSource, out TResult>
    {
        TResult Transform(TSource obj);
    }
```

Comment: Have you read the docs?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.convertall?view=net-6.0 - it expects a method of `Converter<TInput, TOutput>`.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar unfortunately, there is a mistake in this method 
cannot convert from TSource[] to TSource

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Yes I have read it, so is there another way how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`ConvertAll` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.convertall?view=net-6.0) shows that the method has the following signature:

```
public static TOutput[] ConvertAll<TInput,TOutput> (TInput[] array, Converter<TInput,TOutput> converter);
```

As you can see, it takes a `Converter<TInput, TOutput>`. If we look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.converter-2?view=net-6.0) for that, we can see that it's a delegate with the following signature:

```
public delegate TOutput Converter<in TInput,out TOutput>(TInput input);
```

So you should be able to rewrite your convert line like this:

```
var res = Array.ConvertAll(source, new Converter<TSource, TResult>(transformer.Transform));
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/QTKW59455)